# Powershell object doesn't add member

Tags: powershell

For some reason when I wrote this Powershell object, the last member does not get displayed in my result:

```
$resultObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Date -Value $date
$resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TotalPCs -Value $ad
$resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UnmanagedTotal -Value $total
$resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TotalEMEA -Value $adEMEA
$resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UnmanagedEMEA -Value $totalEMEA
$resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TotalAFRICA -Value $adAFRICA
$resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UnmanagedAFRICA -Value $totalAFRICA
$resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TotalAMERICAS -Value $adAMERICAS
$resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UnmanagedAMERICAS -Value $totalAMERICAS
$resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TotalAPAC -Value $adAPAC
$resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UnmanagedAPAC -Value $totalAPAC


$resultObject | ft -AutoSize | out-file -FilePath "C:\BAC\WSUSScripts\KPI\ManagedComputers.txt" -Append
```

I have no clue why since every info is retrieved the same way and for the other member it all works. The last member just falls off.

Comment: `Format-Table -AutoSize` is probably not able to fit all properties on screen so it wil be truncated. It should only be used for console output, not for piping things to a text file. Why not export the object to a structured file like CSV you can open in Excel? `$resultObject | Export-Csv -Path 'theObject.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: How stupid of me I totally didn't think about autosize, thanks for the CSV tip

Comment: I'm with @Theo's statement, but as a side note/hint: It is possible to output data in a table format to a file without truncation:
Use the "-Width"-parameter (with a value like 8192) of Out-File.


The output can even be shown without truncation in the console and PS ISE by enhancing the console buffer size: "$Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = [System.Management.Automation.Host.Size]::new(8192,8192)"